# Getting an error when trying to block public access with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to query all the buckets in my account using boto3. I will then iterate over all the buckets blocking public access on each as I go through.

here is my code:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')

def handler(event, context):
    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        response = client.put_public_access_block(
            Bucket=bucket,
            ContentMD5='string',
            PublicAccessBlockConfiguration={
                'BlockPublicAcls': False,
                'IgnorePublicAcls': False,
                'BlockPublicPolicy': True,
                'RestrictPublicBuckets': True
            },
            ExpectedBucketOwner= '691126532408'
)
```

Here is my error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "expected string or bytes-like object",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/s3PublicAccess.py",
      17,
      "handler",
      "ExpectedBucketOwner= '691126532408'"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      316,
      "_api_call",
      "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      608,
      "_make_api_call",
      "api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      654,
      "_convert_to_request_dict",
      "api_params, operation_model, context)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      686,
      "_emit_api_params",
      "params=api_params, model=operation_model, context=context)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py",
      356,
      "emit",
      "return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py",
      228,
      "emit",
      "return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py",
      211,
      "_emit",
      "response = handler(**kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/handlers.py",
      200,
      "validate_bucket_name",
      "if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I have tried:
Stringing the ExpectedBucketOwner field.

I have experienced this issue when trying to put bucketEncryption on the same iterated list of s3Buckets and am trying to figure it out. Thank you!

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get bucket name from your `bucket`, you have to use `bucket.name`. Also `ContentMD5` is optional, so you can skip it.

Thus, you can try the following (assuming everything else is correct):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')

def handler(event, context):
    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        response = client.put_public_access_block(
            Bucket=bucket.name,
            PublicAccessBlockConfiguration={
                'BlockPublicAcls': False,
                'IgnorePublicAcls': False,
                'BlockPublicPolicy': True,
                'RestrictPublicBuckets': True
            },
            ExpectedBucketOwner= '691126532408'
)
```

Comment: When using this it errors. Here is the root of the message.
Unknown parameter in input: "ExpectedBucketOwner", must be one of: Bucket, ContentMD5, PublicAccessBlockConfiguration: ParamValidationError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/s3PublicAccess.py", line 16, in handler
    ExpectedBucketOwner= '691126532408'

Comment: @aroe `ExpectedBucketOwner` is also optional. Have you tried without it?

Comment: This worked perfectly!!!! Thank you so much for your help again!